# is it possible to cronjob varnish configurations?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm running varnish in front of three http servers.
Since one of these server every morning has scheduled jobs to do and such jobs are really CPU intensive I have created a different configuration in order to round robin the incoming traffic to the other 2 http server. Doing it manually works like a charm,

```
varnish> vcl.list
200        
available     239 boot
active          0 morning

varnish> vcl.use morning
200
```

I'd like to know if there's a way I could script this and with another cron job revert it to boot.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by using the varnishadm utility. For example:

```
varnishadm -T localhost:6082 -S /etc/varnish/secret vcl.use morning
```